# Numpad doesn't work without num lock on

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, numpad

My number pad keys (eg home, end, pg up, pg down) don't work correctly unless numlock is on. When it is, they will produce digits 0-9 perfectly, and shift+numkey will also get the desired/expected behavior, but they do not behave how I want them to otherwise. In most programs they do nothing, but I have observed that they do work when entering my password to login and in VS Code for some reason. **I have checked the universal access setting binding those keys to mouse movement (Mouse Keys) and it is off. Tapping them while running `xev` does create an event.** This only started after my cat had a little too much fun with the keyboard and turned on the screen reader accessibility option, which makes me think that perhaps some other setting has been switched that I'm unaware of. Any help?

Comment: This sounds like ["Mouse Keys"](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/mouse-mousekeys.html.en). If this is the case, you can disable it by opening "Settings" and going to "Universal Access", scrolling down to "Pointing & Clicking", then disabling "Mouse Keys".

Comment: Thanks for the response! As I mentioned in the bold text, I had that turned off. However, I did find out what was wrong- I never turned off the screen reader, and this was preventing the keys from working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My screen reader ended up still being on- it was extremely simple in the end.